# Replacing a part of string with another string in C

Tags: c, string

this is my source code. When I input a string "I am in CSE 2nd year." and replace CSE 2nd(ie loc 9 to 15) by ECE 3rd, I get some garbage vales at the end of string. Also there is a newline at the beggining of rslt2 string. There is something wrong with rslt2. Can anyone please rectify the error?

```
//splitting a string and replace latter part of string by another string
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i,count=0,loc2,scount=0,rcount=0,loc=0;     //scount represents counter for subset and rcount for replacement and loc from where we will split the string
    char str[100],sub[100],newss[100],rslt[100],rslt2[100]; //newss=new substr, rslt and rslt2=former and latter part of original string
    printf("Enter a String:\n");
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    printf("\nString Entered by User:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    puts(str);
    printf("\nLoc Char\n");         //Creates Colums 'Char' and 'Loc'
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        count++;                                //Counts length of String
        printf("%d. %c\n",count,str[i]);    //Prints Characters with it its Corresponding Location
    }
    printf("\n\nLength of String: %d\n\n",count);
    printf("Enter the locations of Characters from where subset will start and end: \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&loc,&loc2);       //stores indices of begining and end of substring
    printf("\n\nSubset formed from Existing String:\n");
    for(i=loc-1;i<loc2;i++)
    {
        scount++;
        sub[i]=str[i];              //stores substring in "sub"
        printf("%c",sub[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nLength of Subset: %d\n",scount);
    for(i=0;i<(loc-1);i++)
    {
        rslt[i]=str[i];         //Stores former part of string in resultant string
    }
    for(i=loc2;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        rslt2[i]=str[i];        //Stores latter part of string in resultant string2
    }
    printf("\n\nEnter a Replacement for Subset(Of Equal Length as that of Subset):\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(newss,100,stdin);
    for(i=0;newss[i]!='\0';i++)
    rcount++;
    printf("\n\nLength of New Subset: %d\n",rcount-1);  //-1 to subtract length of null char
    if(rcount-1!=scount)        //to check whether replacement string and substring are of same len
    printf("\nSince length of both subsets is not same. \nHence Replacement is Not Possible\n");
    else        //Concatination of 3 substrings
    {
        printf("\nResultant String:\n");
        for(i=0;i<(loc-1);i++)
        printf("%c",rslt[i]);
        printf("\n");
        for(i=0;newss[i]!='\0';i++)
        printf("%c",newss[i]);
        for(i=loc2;rslt2[i]!='\0';i++)
        printf("%c",rslt2[i]);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Garbage at end of string is classic symptom of not having a null character to terminate the string.

Comment: you should split your program in multiple function, at least for input, output and one for replacing the substr.

Comment: Why are you using several strings (rslt and rslt2)? You could just directly printf str before loc and after loc2, and print newss in between (or at least use only one where to copy)

Comment: thanx all and is this the correct way of replacing string or is it mandatory to use pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to implement that program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 100

int main( void )
{
    int count, lengthI, lengthR, start, end;
    char initial[MAXL], replacment[MAXL], range[MAXL], result[MAXL];

    // get user input
    printf( "Initial string: " );
    fflush( stdout );
    fgets( initial, MAXL, stdin );

    printf( "Replacement string: " );
    fflush( stdout );
    fgets( replacment, MAXL, stdin );

    printf( "Start and end: ");
    fflush( stdout );
    fgets( range, MAXL, stdin );
    count = sscanf( range, "%d%d", &start, &end );       // indices of beginning and end of range in initial string

    // remove newline character from the input strings, if necessary
    lengthI = strlen( initial );
    if ( lengthI > 0 && initial[lengthI - 1] == '\n' )
        initial[--lengthI] = '\0';

    lengthR = strlen( replacment );
    if ( lengthR > 0 && replacment[lengthR - 1] == '\n' )
        replacment[--lengthR ] = '\0';

    // range checking to verify that user inputs are valid and the resulting string will fit into the buffer
    if ( count != 2 || start < 0 || start > lengthI || end < start || end > lengthI )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Invalid start and end values\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    if ( lengthI + lengthR - (end - start) + 1 > MAXL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Resulting string would be too long\n" );
        exit( 2 );
    }

    // create a new string with the substring replaced
    if ( start > 0 )                                    // copy characters from the initial string up to the start index
        strncpy( result, initial, start );              // note: this step may leave the result string unterminated

    strcpy( &result[start], replacment );               // append the repacement string 
                                                        // guarantees the result string is terminated 

    if ( end < lengthI )                                // append characters from the initial that are after the end index
        strcat( result, &initial[end] );                // terminates the result string (provided that strcat is called) 

    // print the result
    printf( "%s\n", result );
}
```

Comments:

Don't mix `fgets` and `scanf`.  Even if you're aware of the issues involved with doing so, it's still easy to get it wrong. Best to just read lines with `fgets`, and then parse with `sscanf` as necessary.

`fflush(stdin)` is non-standard. `fflush` is only guaranteed to work on `stdout`.  On some systems, `fpurge` can be used to erase unread input.

When dealing with strings in C (aka arrays of characters), range checking is essential.  Buffer overruns are the #1 cause of crashes, unexpected behavior, and security holes in C programs.  Always range check user inputs, and always verify that a newly created string will fit into the buffer provided.

Always make sure that a newly created string ends with a null character (aka '\0'), and be sure to include that null character when calculating buffer sizes.

Note that in the sample code, `strncpy` may leave the string unterminated.  The subsequent call to `strcpy` will terminate the string.  The `strcat` function will also terminate the string.  However, the call to `strcat` is conditional based on user input. Hence, without the call to 'strcpy', we'd have extra work to do to guarantee the the string gets its mandatory null terminator.

Answer (score -1):

use negated scanf ie `scanf(" %[^\n]",str_name);` instead of `gets();`

Comment: Fix the typo inside scanf.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay is it ok now? :)